# Update error column parameter does not exist

Tags: sql, teradata

Trying to execute this query I've this error:

```
Update failed. 3810: Column/parameter 'edw_workarea.A.A' does not exist.
```

I'm using Teradata database.

```
UPDATE A
FROM   EDW_WORKAREA.bs A,
       (
           SELECT stg.ccir_ind_id,
                  stg.orig_ccir_id
           FROM   EDW_WORKAREA.se stg
                  INNER JOIN best_svc bc
                       ON  stg.ccir_ind_id = bc.ccir_ind_id
           WHERE  stg.deliverability_score < '6'
                  AND stg.ccir_ind_id IN (SELECT stg.ccir_ind_id
                                          FROM   EDW_WORKAREA.se stg
                                          WHERE  stg.orig_ccir_id IS NULL
                                                 OR  stg.orig_ccir_id = ''
                                          GROUP BY
                                                 stg.ccir_ind_id
                                          HAVING COUNT(*) = 1)
       ) t

SET A.orig_ccir_id = t.orig_ccir_id
    WHERE A.ccir_ind_id = t.ccir_ind_id;
```

All the tables and columns exist in database. And subquery in t was executing successfully alone.

Can any one point me where the error is ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Teradata, you shouldn't qualify your columns in the SET clause, so change your SQL to something like:

```
update EDW_WORKAREA.bs
from (
    select ...
) t
set orig_ccir_id = t.orig_ccir_id
where EDW_WORKAREA.bs.ccir_ind_id = t.ccir_ind_id;
```

Comment: where EDW_WORKAREA.bs.ccir_ind_id = t.ccir_ind_id;   adding this to your code worked for me . with out it i got ccir_ind_id is ambigious. Thanks Dan!!