# Stored procedure is trying to call to the database inside the database it is created in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I created a procedure in teradata

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE ABC.SHOWTABLE (my_table VARCHAR(30),my_database VARCHAR(30)) 
BEGIN

DECLARE sqlstr VARCHAR(500);
SET sqlstr = 'SHOW TABLE ' || my_database || 
            '.' || my_table  ;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlstr;
END;



call ABC.SHOWTABLE (XYZ,MYTABLE);
```

It is showing error
Column/Parameter 'ABC.SHOWTABLE.XYZ' does not exist. 
Elapsed time = 00:00:00.011

why it is looking inside procedure

Comment: Probably a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18658507/1531971

Comment: What are the values you are passing to my_table and my_database? And shouldn't the lengths of those variable match the maximum valid lengths for a database and table name? Surely it's not 30.

Comment: #1: Your parameters are VARCHAR, of course you must pass them as strings, i.e. quoted. #2: you can't use `SHOW TABLE` in a Stored Procedure.

Comment: #1: Would look like `call ABC.SHOWTABLE ('XYZ','MYTABLE');` #2: there is no workaround here :(